# https api request is not working with https.get(url)

Tags: javascript, express, https

I need to pull the weather API data from

> https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=f5f45b956fc64a2482370828211902&q=London

It gives a response when pasted in the web browser as well as in postman. But, once incorporated in javascript **https.get** it fails by continuously loading the browsers and hanging the terminal with unwanted informations.

**app.js :**

```
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");

const app = express();


app.get("/",function(req, res){

  const url = "https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=f5f45b956fc64a2482370828211902&q=London";

  https.get(url,function(response){
    //console.log(response);

    response.on("data",function(data){
      const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
      const temp = weatherData.current.temp_c;
      const weatherDescription = weatherData.current.condition.text;
    });
  });

  res.send("Server is up and running");

});


app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Started on port 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the specific request that you posted using `https.get()` and it worked for me. So it will be difficult to figure out what is the exact problem without more information, for example about how exactly it is failing for you. What messages are you seeing on the console? How are you accessing the result of the request, so what makes you think that the request didn't work?

But apart from that, that is not how you usually make requests in Node. The "data" event may be emitted multiple times if the response arrives in multiple chunks, so the way you do it will only work if you are lucky and the response arrives in a single chunk. The proper way to do this by hand would be to listen to all "data" events, concatenate the result, and then when the "end" event is emitted, parse the concatenated data. However, it is rather uncommon to do this by hand.

A more common way to do this would be to use a library such as [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) to make the request for you. For example like this: `fetch(url).then((res) => res.json()).then((weatherData) => { const weatherDescription = weatherData.current.condition.text; })`.

Comment: Once i run it using nodeman ( nodeman app.js) , it starts listening to the port 3000. But once I run localhost:3000/ on my browser, the browser keeps loading and in the terminal where i ran nodeman (hyper) it shows a response that is not specific to the original or expected respone. [ fetch(url).then((res) => res.json()).then((weatherData) => { const weatherDescription = weatherData.current.condition.text; }) .............to ...........fetch(url).then((res) => res.json()).then((weatherData) => { const weatherDescription = weatherData.current.condition.text; }) ]

Comment: I could make a correct response using node-fetch . Thanks for that. But how do i get to console.log the temp_c and weather description from the api ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to `console.log` the weather information? In that case just run `console.log(temp, weatherDescription)`. Are you trying to send the information to the browser? In that case, remove your `res.send()` call and instead add something like `res.send(temp + '\n' + weatherDescription)`.

Comment: Also, I don't know what nodeman is. Why don't you run the app with `node app.js` or `nodejs app.js` (depending on your system)?